# Node Socket server very slow performance

Tags: mysql, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I  have build chat application in  Php + Mysql + Node Socket technology.

Application Hosted in aws LightSail Server with 1 GB Ram & same CPU.

In Live when over 200 + user join in chat room, application will hang [vert slow or unresponsive].
When check server status CPU & Ram usage very low.

what will be the issue?
where will find these logs.

Thanks,

Comment: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.